# Управление состоянием React приложения, когда логика определена вне компонента

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть компонент `App`, который пробрасывает массив с адресами (locations) в компонент `Map`, представляющий карту с метками по указанным адресам, в компонент `List`, представляющий список адресов, и в `Input`, позволяющий добавлять новые адреса (в моей терминологии это location point).

Я вынес логику CRUD операций с адресами в отдельные функции - чтобы немного упросить задачу написания unit-тестов для этих функций и убрать нагромождение логики, которая по существу является достаточно универсальной и может быть позднее повторно использована.

В приложение на текущий момент не используется никакой state management (ни Redux, ни MobX).

Вопрос исходит из этого: В классе приходится создавать функции "провайдеры", которые обеспечивают обновление `state.locations` за счет вызова функций с реальной логикой (в примере это `App.addLocPoint`, вызывающий `addLocationPoint` для получения обновленного массива locations) и передавать эти провайдеры дочерним компонентам, чтобы они их вызывали при соответствующем действии пользователя (например, добавление адреса через `Input.onSubmit`).

Код, обсуждаемого примера (приведен для пояснения, не запустится так как нет импортов):

```js
// Adds a new location point
const addLocactionPoint = (locations: array, address: string) => {
  // ...
  return updatedLocations;
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      locations: [],
    }

    // bind addLocPoint, etc.
  }

  addLocPoint(address) {
    this.setState(state => {
      addLocactionPoint(state.locations, address);
    });
  }

  // ...

  render() {
    return (
      <Input onSubmit={ this.addLocPoint } />
      <List 
        onDrag={ this.moveLocPoint }
        onDelete={ this.deleteLocPoint } 
      />
      <Map data={ this.state.locations } />
    );
  }
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Является ли такое решение приемлемой практикой? Возможно, есть способ обойтись без этих "провайдеров" и как-то иначе обновлять state, не нагружая App огромным количество логики и не прибегая к Redux (или MobX)?
Или, возможно, для таких кейсов хорошим решением все же будет использовать стороннюю библиотеку для управления state?

Буду признателен за рекомендации по вопросу (благодарен даже за ссылку на материал для изучения по данной теме).

Answer (score 0):

Это хороший (и обычно используемый) способ управлять состоянием в Vanilla React, если не используются сторонние библиотеки, созданные для этой задачи. [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) может немного упростить задачу, если нужно передавать состояние (в данном случае locations) большому количеству вложенных компонентов.

Сами функции, обновляющие состояние (addLocationPoint, etc), можно превратить в updater-функции, которые будут передавать в setState(), и внутри них асинхронно обновлять
состояние:

```js
// Функция-updater, которая возвращает функцию, принимающую текущий
// state и возвращающую новый обновленный массив c адресами
const addLocationPoint = (address) => (state) => {
  // Concat не изменяет исходный массив, а возвращает новый
  updatedLocations = state.locations.concat([
    { id: 0, address: address }
  ]);
  
  return updatedLocations;
}

class App extends React.Component {
  ...
  addLocPoint(address) {
    this.setState(addLocationPoint(address));
  }
  ...
```

Такая функция использует концепцию higher order function и использует [вторую форму setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate), принимающую функцию.

Похожая идея как раз используется в Redux action creators.

Если такие updater-функции вынести еще и в отдельный модуль, то их будет легко тестировать независимо от компонента и, в тоже время, компонент не зависимо от них (в этом случаем updater'ы можно подменять (eng. *to mock*) с помощью `jest.mock`)

*Перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52890827/9575622) пользователя @estus с англоязычного stackoverflow, с дополнениями от автора вопроса.*